How to prevent ChatGPT web interface from censoring the links?
Sometimes, ChatGPT provides me with links to external sources. I can see the URL briefly when the answer is generated, but then, links in the response are not functional. The URL is stripped and the link looks like this:
<a rel="noreferrer" target="_new">text</a>

Is there some setting or plugin I can use to turn off this "protection"?

It seems like a bug in the web interface when ChatGPT returns a response where the URL is missing. I've tried asking it multiple ways for the URL and a couple times I saw the URL flash on the screen and disappear when it converted it to a clickable link. So, this lead me to two possible solutions:
Option 1: Click the copy button and it will include the URL that is being stripped from the answer.

Option 2: Ask GPT to return it's response in markdown format.

Note: on another look, the URLs that are being stripped out (in my few tests) have all been invalid. So, maybe ChatGPT has logic to remove invalid URLs?
